# How can I search old deleted emails going back a couple of years in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

Is it possible to search old Hotmail/Outlook deleted emails? If so, how please?

Answer (score -1):

NO not if it's be a while I have Outlook and I had Hotmail and neither one saves deleted email. unless you reclaim the it in the same day or with in a short time period. But the best way to know for sure is go into your deleted files in your Outlook email account, or go up to your delete tab that you click to  delete your e-mail and there should be a pop-up tab or area there where you are given the choice to reclaim or search for any or all your deleted mail as long as it has not been to long of a time, between the time you deleted said mail and tried or try to reclaim it.  Good Luck,  friend.